# How can I get the eclipse XML editor to ignore the error, "An element with the identifier 'id' must appear in the document"?

Tags: xml, eclipse, validation

I am working on a DocBook project and have split the chapters into separate files. Many of the chapters have cross-references to items in other chapters. The result is that the editor flags errors indicating that the id was not found in the document.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE preface PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD DocBook XML V4.5//EN" "../../docbook-xml-4.5/docbookx.dtd">
<chapter id="chapter-actions">
    <title>Aktionen</title>
    <para>This chapter contains an in-depth reference for the actions.</para>
...
    <section><variablelist>

        <varlistentry>
            <term>Value</term>
            <listitem>
                <para>This is the expected value from the addressed input. It can contain a character string or
                a numeric value. Numeric values may contain masked values. See <xref linkend="glos-mask"/> for more information on masked values. 
                See <xref linkend="glos-value"/> for a list of valid formats.</para>
            </listitem>
        </varlistentry>
...


An element with the identifier "glos-value" must appear in the document
```

Is there a way to suppress this error? I have checked the validation preferences for the project but could not spot anything there.

Answer (score 0):

Renaming the chapter files to `*.dbk` did the trick for me. Not sure why but they now validate ok but still have the DocBook DTD support in the editor.